# How to programmatically determine which version of .NET Standard is supported by the current version of .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I'm looking for some API, registry setting, xml/json file that would tell me, at runtime, which level of .NET Standard is implemented by the current framework.

For instance, this API would tell me, in a few years: .NET Standard 2.2 is supported by the current runtime because you're running .NET Framework 4.8.5.

Update: The procedure needs to work on a developer machine with the SDKs installed.

Comment: How would it know? If new APIs are added to .NET Standard that already existed in a particular version of the framework, that version can be declared to support that version of the standard with *no* code releases

Comment: Good point. The information could be present in some SDK. Currently, I haven't found it in the .NET Core SDK.

Comment: I have found a part of the answer in `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.SupportedTargetFrameworks.props`. If I assume that the SDK will not install on a .NET Framework of a lower version than required, I have the full answer. Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever for putting me on the way.

Comment: The proof of the pudding is in the eating. If your .NET Standard 2.2 library will not build with tools that reference it in an application targeting .NET 4.8.5, it is not supported. Otherwise, it is. Typically, those tools don't even know *themselves* if that will succeed before they attempt to do it, since it all depends on how the library dependencies are configured. This is one of those "why do you think you need to know this" questions, with a dash of "why do you think you can do better than the tooling".

Comment: Note that it is a build time question, not a runtime question -- .NET Standard is not a platform. An end user doesn't know or care what .NET Standard version you've been using in your libraries, only whether the .NET platform your executable is targeting can be run. (Which can be tricky enough in case of minor version changes.)

Comment: You could use NuGet's `DefaultCompatibilityProvider` to determine compatibility between known frameworks ([example](https://github.com/joelverhagen/NuGetTools/blob/aed8fc6fb62b5cc6949c8c4e6e458205ad3a8cf3/src/Knapcode.NuGetTools.Logic.Direct/Wrappers/FrameworkLogic.cs)) or directly use the [DefaultFrameworkMappings](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/dev/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Frameworks/DefaultFrameworkMappings.cs) class of `NuGet.Frameworks`.

Comment: Good idea @MartinUllrich. Actually my use case is to consume a NuGet package, so I need to figure out which lib directory is best.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in the comments that you're looking for a way to programmatically determine which Nuget `lib` directory to install. You can use the [Nuget.Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Frameworks/) package from Microsoft, which provides a `DefaultCompatibilityProvider.IsCompatible` function.

Using it would look like this:

```cs
var currentVersion = GetCurrentFramework();
var selectedPackage = Directory
    .GetDirectories(Path.Combine("path/to/nuget/package/", "lib"))
    .Last(lib => DefaultCompatibilityProvider.Instance.IsCompatible(
        currentVersion,
        NuGetFramework.Parse(Path.GetFileName(lib))
    ));

// helper method for getting the currently running framework
private NuGetFramework GetCurrentFramework() => 
    NuGetFramework.Parse(
        Assembly
            .GetEntryAssembly()?
            .GetCustomAttribute<TargetFrameworkAttribute>()?
            .FrameworkName
    );
```

The source for this package and the `DefaultCompatibilityProvider` class is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/dev/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Frameworks/DefaultFrameworkMappings.cs).

Comment: If you're parsing a nuget file with the Nuget.Framework, there is `PackageArchiveReader.GetSupportedFrameworks()` which will return a `IEnumerble<NuGetFramework>` which can be used instead of parsing the folders within the archive.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a class that is used to get information related to the .NET runtime. Specifically, the `FrameworkDescription` property is suppose to return a string that indicates the current ".NET Installation that the app is running in". Though, if you are using .NET Core, prior to version 3.0 RC1, you might end up with an inaccurate version number. The recent RC1 release states that this is fixed going forward.

To get the framework version string:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

Console.WriteLine($"RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription: {RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription}");
```

This will print a sting that corresponds to your current .NET Framework version that the assembly is running on. One of either `".NET Core"`, `".NET Native"`, or `".NET Framework"` followed by the current version string.